# How to create sqlite file in web application instead of windows application in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sqlite, soap

```
protected void callWebService()
{
    DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
    WebReference.plFairPriceShopDetails[] arr = obj.FairPriceShopRequestAck("158500100002", "3058505610803243", "ECIL", "84:EB:18:EC:54:3A", "v1.0", dt, "alloc032016", dt, dt, 1);

    DataTable dataT = new DataTable();
    dataT = objToDataTable(arr);


    string connStr = @" DataSource = C:\Users\gobol\Desktop\UK.db; Version =3";
    //After finister

    Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

    // create a new database connection:
    sqlite_conn = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
    //  sqlite_conn = new Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connStr);

    // open the connection:
    sqlite_conn.Open();

    // create a new SQL command:
    sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

    // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));";

    // Now lets execute the SQL ;D
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Lets insert something into our new table:
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (id, text) VALUES (1, 'Test Text 1');";

    // And execute this again ;D
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // ...and inserting another line:
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (id, text) VALUES (2, 'Test Text 2');";

    // And execute this again ;D
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // But how do we read something out of our table ?
    // First lets build a SQL-Query again:
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";

    // Now the SQLiteCommand object can give us a DataReader-Object:
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // The SQLiteDataReader allows us to run through the result lines:
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) // Read() returns true if there is still a result line to read
    {
        // Print out the content of the text field:
        //System.Console.WriteLine(sqlite_datareader["text"]);
        string op = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
    }

    // We are ready, now lets cleanup and close our connection:
    sqlite_conn.Close();
}
```

I have to create a sqlite file in system while interaction  with soap api .Here Soap api return some data So from that data i have to create the database file. I can able to create through windows application but not for web application because after that i have to upload database file in particular device who call the web application.

Answer (score 1):

the file downloaded in IIS Express under Program Files folder

```
      public bool connectToSQLiteCreateDB(string DBName)
    {
        // create a new database connection:
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + DBName + ".db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

        try
        {
            // open the connection:
            sqlite_conn.Open();

            // create a new SQL command:
            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

            // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:

            // Create Entilement Table 
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE entitlement (" +
      "commodity_name_en    character varying," +
      "commodity_name_ll    character varying," +
      );";

            // Now lets execute the SQL ;D
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlite_conn.Close();
            return true;

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
             var err=ex.Message;
             return false;
        }
               }

     public void connectToSQLiteInsertIntoDB(string DBName)
    {
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + DBName + ".db;Version=3;New=False;");

        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        // create a new SQL command:
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        //// Lets insert something into our new table:
        //sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (id, text) VALUES (1, 'Test Text 1');";

        //// And execute this again ;D
        //sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //// ...and inserting another line:
        //sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (id, text) VALUES (2, 'Test Text 2');";

        //// And execute this again ;D
        //sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //// But how do we read something out of our table ?
        //// First lets build a SQL-Query again:
        //sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";

        //// Now the SQLiteCommand object can give us a DataReader-Object:
        //sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //// The SQLiteDataReader allows us to run through the result lines:
        //while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) // Read() returns true if there is still a result line to read
        //{
        //    // Print out the content of the text field:
        //    //System.Console.WriteLine(sqlite_datareader["text"]);
        //    string op = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
        //}

    }
```